# How to select top five record based on particular condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have below given table

```
ID NAME  
1 100  
2 90  
3 80  
4 70  
5 60  
6 60  
7 60
```

If 6th and 7th record in table having same value as 5th then it will return 6th and 7th. But if it is different from 5th then it will return only top 5 records.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: is this applicable for only 6th and 7th record?

Comment: What if a `Name` is repeated in the 1-4th ID instead of in the last ID-group? So for example if `ID=1` and `ID=2` would have the same `Name`? Would that count as one row or two?

Comment: Yes it is only for 6th and 7th

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you needed 5 top unique values, you can use [`DENSE_RANK()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173825.aspx)

```
select id,name from 
(select id, name, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Name DESC) as r from tbl ) t
where r<=5
```

**WORKING FIDDLE:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8da1e

Comment: This works only because the sample data is ordered by Name DESC accidentially.

Comment: Also,  the ID  determines the order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT ID, Name
FROM dbo.Tablename
WHERE Name IN (SELECT TOP 5 Name FROM dbo.Tablename order by Name desc)
order by Name desc
```

Comment: But the ID  determines the order.

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 5 WITH TIES id, name from t order by name desc
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `RANK()` which is similar to `DENSE_RANK()`

Try below query -

```
select id,name from 
(select id, name, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Name DESC) as r from yourtbl) t
where r<=5
```

Comment: This works only because the sample data is ordered by Name DESC accidentially.

Comment: Also, the ID  determines the order, only on the last of TOP n the whole name-group should be taken.